# A best way to fit mice() to a factorial study design

Tags: r, missing-data, r-mice

I have a factorial study design.

For each observation, there is a combination of the two factors (3 x 3) that are missing. I have performed both a `chisquare` and a `Little's test` to check whether data are missing as MCAR pattern and so it resulted (with the chi-square test, there is no association between the two observed and missing values).

Now I struggling with the method to choose to impute data. Being the variable normally distributed and continuous I've opted for `pmm` but I am not sure it might be the correct way due to this design.

Can anyone suggest something more specific?

Here is the data structure. The column having factorial levels to which I referring to are  `q` and `w`

```
dt <- tibble::tribble(
  ~f,  ~q,       ~w,      ~m,      ~VAR1,            ~VAR2,            ~VAR3,            ~VAR4,            ~VAR5,            ~VAR6,            ~miss,
  "3", "medium", "west",  "opono", 562.043178225707, 568.970169826137, 577.156037256044, 567.498180346941, 572.076341064459, 574.774223561689, 1,
  "3", "medium", "story", "opono", 565.281147016741, 570.567233719795, 577.180178600797, 570.006855833371, 572.407617246296, 575.827304179063, 1,
  "3", "medium", "side",  "opono", 565.124165466063, 570.51987609038,  577.357864860489, 569.353224777675, 570.525930106581, 573.368662115429, 1,
  "3", "low",    "west",  "opono", 556.105161267006, 562.933778604826, 566.859356471408, 567.282762095302, 570.296353575057, 571.859463603291, 1,
  "3", "low",    "story", "opono", 558.9191937444,   564.873410440901, 569.356122801201, 567.855921468843, 570.231712506384, 571.992766432843, 1,
  "3", "low",    "side",  "opono", 561.089399192576, 566.829488261267, 572.074153197824, 569.664181971811, 572.132317217948, 574.115841254771, 1,
)
```